# jwplayer file name from C:

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jwplayer

I have an application which plays a media with jwplayer.. and i have this code:

```
 jwplayer("VideoContainer").setup({
                autostart: true,
                flashplayer: "swf/player.swf",
                file: "name.flv",
                height: 270,
                width: 480

      });
```

when i put my name.flv in the application, the file recognizes the path, but when i have a file from C:.. its not loading the file for ex : file:"C:\....\name.flv"..how can i solve this problem? thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

**Client** machines cannot play media files available **locally** on their drive with **online flash players** (with url = http://servername/playerapplication/playerpage), for security reasons, unless they **upload** the files to the server.

> Check these links:
>   http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/feature-suggestions/910/can-read-from-a-absolute-path#comment-57954;
>   http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/setup-issues-and-embedding/8872/local-media-files

But you still can play a media file available on the **server**'s **`C:\`** drive, **online** from **any machine**, by using a **streaming server** like [Wowza Media Server](http://www.wowzamedia.com) or [Red5](http://www.red5server.org).

For Wowza server, you have to do the following:

1. Create a new empty folder for your
   application (e.g. myplayerapp) under
   `[wowza-install-dir]/applications`
2. Create another new empty folder
   (myplayerapp) under
   `[wowza-install-dir]/conf`, that
   includes **`Application.xml`** (Copy
   `[wowza-install-dir]/conf/Application.xml`),
   where you set `Streams/StorageDir`
   to `C:`

> http://www.streamalot.com/wowza-tips&tricks-jwplayer.shtml

And your code will be like this:

```
 jwplayer("VideoContainer").setup({
                autostart: true,
                flashplayer: "swf/player.swf",
                file: "name.flv", //if your file is under C:\test, it will be file: "test/name.flv"...
                height: 270,
                width: 480,
                bufferlength: 2,
                streamer: "rtmp://servername/myplayerapp"
      });
```

Note that the Wowza Media Server should be started before running the player page.

Otherwise, to open **local files** on any machine, you need to open the player **offline** from every machine (e.g. C:\webserver\playerapplication\playerpage) and all the files (`swf`, `js`, `media files`) must have their locations set as **local paths**, as follows:

```
 jwplayer("VideoContainer").setup({
                autostart: true,
                flashplayer: "file:///C:/webserver/playerapplication/swf/player.swf", //or "C:\\...\\player.swf" or "C:/.../player.swf"
                file: "file:///C:/name.flv",
                height: 270,
                width: 480
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
jwplayer("VideoContainer").setup({                 
    autostart: true,                 
    flashplayer: "swf/player.swf",                 
    file: "C:\\name.flv",                 
    height: 270,                 
    width: 480        
});
```